# Create table after specific text found in Word document using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I see the document of python-docx for handling Word files in python. For the tutorial, I can use the `add_table` to create the table in the last line.

I want to add the tables with the subheading when I detect the specific word found in the Word file. This code is not adding tables after the text found. How do I modify my code?

```py
for i in range(tableCount):
    df = data_frames[f'df_{i}'].reset_index(drop=True) # Reset the index
    df = df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'])
    headers = df.columns.tolist()
    data = df.values.tolist()
    text_search = "A list is find here"
    sub_heading = "2.5." + str(i)
    document = Document('./my_document.docx')
    
    for p in document.paragraphs:
        if text_search in paragraph.text:
            ##  Create the heading in here
            heading = document.add_heading(sub_heading,level=2)
            ##  Create the table in here
            table = document.add_table(rows=len(data)+1, cols=len(headers))
```

Comment: All table that i've tried to add are systematically inserted in the bottom of my document,Thats the issue!